# If $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4$ are roots of $x^4 +(2-\sqrt{3})x^2 +2+\sqrt{3}=0$ ....

Tags: polynomials, roots, symmetric-polynomials

Problem :

If $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4$ are roots of $x^4 +(2-\sqrt{3})x^2 +2+\sqrt{3}=0$ then the value of $(1-\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)(1-\alpha_3)(1-\alpha_4)$ is

(a) 2$\sqrt{3}$

(b)  5

(c)  1

(d)  4

My approach :

Discriminant of this problem is :

$(2-\sqrt{3})^2- 4(2+\sqrt{3}) <0$

Therefore roots are imaginary.

Now how to consider the roots here... please suggest.. thanks

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

$$p(x)=x^4 +(2-\sqrt{3})x^2 +2+\sqrt{3}=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)(x-\alpha_4)$$

Comment: I didn't get  that... please give details a bit.. thanks

Comment: It is almost obvious that if you put $x = 1$ you get the answer as 5. The equation in the above answer is a general result : if $\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \ldots, \alpha_{n}$ are the $n$ roots of $P(x) = a_{0}x^{n} + a_{1}x^{n - 1} + \cdots + a_{n - 1}x + a_{n}$ then $P(x) = a_{0}(x - \alpha_{1})(x - \alpha_{2})\cdots(x - \alpha_{n})$

Comment: @sultan What do you not understand? Does the equation I wrote make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

Let give a polinom $p_4(x)=a_4 x^4+b_3x^3+c_2x^2+d_1x+e$. Use formula:

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=-\frac{b}{a}$$
$$x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_4+x_3x_4=\frac{c}{a}$$
$$x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4=-\frac{d}{a}$$
$$x_1x_2x_3x_4=\frac{e}{a}$$
where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ is rrots of the given polinom.

For the given example, we have: $x^4+0\cdot x^3 +(2-\sqrt 3)x^2+0\cdot x + 2+\sqrt 3=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $a=-1, b=0, c=2-\sqrt 3, d=0, e=2+\sqrt 3$

$$\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3+\alpha_4=0$$
$$\alpha_1\alpha_2+\alpha_1\alpha_3+\alpha_2\alpha_3+\alpha_1\alpha_4+\alpha_2\alpha_4+\alpha_3\alpha_4=2-\sqrt 3$$
$$\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3+\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_4+\alpha_1\alpha_3\alpha_4+\alpha_2\alpha_3\alpha_4=0$$
$$\alpha_1x\alpha_2\alpha_3\alpha_4=2-\sqrt 3$$

$(1-\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)(1-\alpha_3)(1-\alpha_4)=1-(\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3+\alpha_4)+(\alpha_1\alpha_2+\alpha_1\alpha_3+\alpha_2\alpha_3+\alpha_1\alpha_4+\alpha_2\alpha_4+\alpha_3\alpha_4)-(\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3+\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_4+\alpha_1\alpha_3\alpha_4+\alpha_2\alpha_3\alpha_4)+\alpha_1x\alpha_2\alpha_3\alpha_4=2-\sqrt 3+2+\sqrt 3=4$

$d)$ $4$ is answer.

Comment: A slight mistake at the end. You forgot the $1$ in $1 - (\alpha_{1} + \alpha_{2} + \alpha_{3} + \alpha_{4}) + \cdots$ and the right answer is $5$

Answer (score 0):

I provide another method, which is useful when we are asked to find some linear transformed sum (or product) of roots.

Let $y=1-x$. Then if $\alpha_i$ are the roots of the original equation, then $1-\alpha_i$ are the roots to the equation $$(1-y)^4+(2-\sqrt{3})(1-y)^2+2+\sqrt{3}=0\tag{*}$$
Then the required term is just the product of root of $(*)$. Hence, by Vieta's formula, we have $$\prod^4_{i=1}(1-\alpha_i)=\dfrac{2+\sqrt{3}+2-\sqrt{3}+1}{(-1)^4}=5$$
Pretty elegant method :)

Comment: how did u get the product of roots?

Comment: Vieta's formula, $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ be a quartic polynomial. Then the product of its zero is equal to $\dfrac{e}{a}$.

Comment: isnt that just 2+sqrt(3)?

Comment: show me how ok?

Comment: Nono, now we apply on $(*)$ which is a quartic in $\mathbf{y}$. So you need to consider the **Constant** terms of $(*)$, which is $2+\sqrt{3}$, $2-\sqrt{3}$ from the $(\mathbf{1}-y)^2$ and $1$ from $(\mathbf{1}-y)^4$. And the leading coefficient is obvious.

Comment: where did the idea to let y=1-x come from?

Comment: Because now the required form is in a product of $1-\alpha_i$, so it seems to be attractive to investigate $y=1-x$.